# getopt library won't load

Tags: lisp, clisp

[76]> (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op 'getopt)
; loading system definition from getopt.asd into #
;; Loading file getopt.asd ...
; registering # as GETOPT
; registering # as GETOPT-TESTS

*** - Program stack overflow. RESET

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, I can get other libraries to load this way, but I'm new to this implementation, and young to lisp, so what do I know...

What could I be doing differently?

This is GNU clisp from Ubuntu 10.04, getopt 1.2.0-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, apparently the answer is "Don't use clisp or gcl". The library loads without complaint in sbcl.

Not very satisfying, but at least there's a solution.